# Calculate price based on selection from - to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate price based on the from - to selection and what day is.

I can't understand the logic why is not working.

I try to get to_time and than subtract from_time and i will get how much time you selected and than add that time to price.

```
get_time_daily = 12 - 6
daily_price = get_time_daily * 45;
```

On simple from - to works well, but when i was introduced, nightly and Sunday price i get lost.

How i can calculate price based on 3 criteria, daily price, nightly price and Sunday price?

```js
$("#weeksdatecleaning").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  minDate: 2,
  altField: '#selectedDatecleaning',
  onSelect: function() {
    var day = date.getUTCDay();
    if (day == '6') {
      today_is_sunday = 1;
    } else {
      today_is_sunday = 0;
    }

  },
});

let get_from_time_val = $('.from').val();
let get_to_time_val = $('.to').val();
let get_time_daily = 0;
let get_time_nightly = 0;
let get_time_sunday = 0;

if (get_from_time_val < 32 && get_to_time_val < 33) {
  get_time_daily = get_to_time_val - get_from_time_val;

} else if (get_from_time_val > 33 && get_to_time_val < 35) {
  get_time_nightly = get_to_time_val - get_from_time_val;
} else if (get_from_time_val > 36 && get_to_time_val > 36 && today_is_sunday === 1) {
  get_time_sunday = get_to_time_val - get_from_time_val;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="timepicker">
  <div class="from-date">
    <select id="from" name="from" class="from">
      <option value="1">07:00</option>
      <option value="2">07:30</option>
      <option value="3">08:00</option>
      <option value="4">08:30</option>
      <option value="5">09:00</option>
      <option value="6">09:30</option>
      <option value="7">10:00</option>
      <option value="8">10:30</option>
      <option value="9">11:00</option>
      <option value="10">11:30</option>
      <option value="11">12:00</option>
      <option value="12">12:30</option>
      <option value="13">13:00</option>
      <option value="14">13:30</option>
      <option value="15">14:00</option>
      <option value="16">14:30</option>
      <option value="17">15:00</option>
      <option value="18">15:30</option>
      <option value="19">16:00</option>
      <option value="20">16:30</option>
      <option value="21">17:00</option>
      <option value="22">17:30</option>
      <option value="23">18:00</option>
      <option value="24">18:30</option>
      <option value="25">19:00</option>
      <option value="26">19:30</option>
      <option value="27">20:00</option>
      <option value="28">20:30</option>
      <option value="29">21:00</option>
      <option value="30">21:30</option>
      <option value="31">22:00</option>
      <option value="32">22:30</option>
      <option value="33">23:00</option>
      <option value="34">23:30</option>
      <option value="35">00:00</option>
      <option value="36">00:30</option>
      <option value="37">01:00</option>
      <option value="38">01:30</option>
      <option value="39">02:00</option>
      <option value="40">02:30</option>
      <option value="41">03:00</option>
      <option value="42">03:30</option>
      <option value="43">04:00</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="to-date">
    <select id="to" name="to" class="to">
      <option value="1">07:00</option>
      <option value="2">07:30</option>
      <option value="3">08:00</option>
      <option value="4">08:30</option>
      <option value="5">09:00</option>
      <option value="6">09:30</option>
      <option value="7">10:00</option>
      <option value="8">10:30</option>
      <option value="9">11:00</option>
      <option value="10">11:30</option>
      <option value="11">12:00</option>
      <option value="12">12:30</option>
      <option value="13">13:00</option>
      <option value="14">13:30</option>
      <option value="15">14:00</option>
      <option value="16">14:30</option>
      <option value="17">15:00</option>
      <option value="18">15:30</option>
      <option value="19">16:00</option>
      <option value="20">16:30</option>
      <option value="21">17:00</option>
      <option value="22">17:30</option>
      <option value="23">18:00</option>
      <option value="24">18:30</option>
      <option value="25">19:00</option>
      <option value="26">19:30</option>
      <option value="27">20:00</option>
      <option value="28">20:30</option>
      <option value="29">21:00</option>
      <option value="30">21:30</option>
      <option value="31">22:00</option>
      <option value="32">22:30</option>
      <option value="33">23:00</option>
      <option value="34">23:30</option>
      <option value="35">00:00</option>
      <option value="36">00:30</option>
      <option value="37">01:00</option>
      <option value="38">01:30</option>
      <option value="39">02:00</option>
      <option value="40">02:30</option>
      <option value="41">03:00</option>
      <option value="42">03:30</option>
      <option value="43">04:00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `get_from_time_val` and `get_to_time_val` are strings

Comment: parseInt($('.from').val()) will fix the issue?

Comment: I dont know but youre currently doing maths with strings which isnt a good idea